# go test `-parallel` vs `-test.parallel` which flag gets precedence?

Tags: testing, go

Difference between `go test`'s two flags `-parallel` and `-test.parallel` and which flag gets precedence?

```
-parallel n
            Allow parallel execution of test functions that call t.Parallel.
            The value of this flag is the maximum number of tests to run
            simultaneously; by default, it is set to the value of GOMAXPROCS.
            Note that -parallel only applies within a single test binary.
            The 'go test' command may run tests for different packages
            in parallel as well, according to the setting of the -p flag
            (see 'go help build').
```

Above documentation says that the number of tests that are run in parallel are equal to `GOMAXPROCS` if nothing is provided, but the behavior is not like that for me. Because I am running tests on a machine that has only 4 cores. But for me 8 tests run in parallel, so the behavior is more like following:

```
-test.parallel int
        maximum test parallelism (default 8)
```

So what is the difference between the two? When to use which flag.

### More Information

I am running all tests on a single package which has 9 tests, all of them are run parallely and all those exist in single test function.

Comment: You must show a) code and b) how you execute the tests (via `go test` or via running a compiled test binary) and show the value of GOMAXPROCS (in env and during execution).

Comment: I think this is a correct behavior, so I am running end to end tests against a cluster in a VM which has 4 cores, but my host machine has 8 cores so the functionality seems fine. Sorry about the noise.

Comment: @Volker I don't think the code is at all relevant - this is a simple question about the flags documented on the `go test` command and is not specific to the code being run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-test.` flags are generated by `go test` command. The `go test` command produces a `pkg.test` binary on the fly and runs it with modified arguments. All the recognized arguments passed to `go test` will be converted. So, in your case: `-parallel n` becomes `-test.parallel n`.

So this command:

```
go test -parallel 6
```

creates:

```
pkg.test -test.parallel 6
```